# How to render tables in Slack

Tags: slack-api, slack-commands

I have a slack application that responds with formatted data in mrkdwn but it would be nice to have the information presented in table form like so

[image: sample view from ipushpull]

Am trying to implement this but cant quite find how to format this message. The only close solution i have is taking a screen grab of the table and sending it instead but that affects the applications response time. Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: It is mind-boggling to me that Slack does not prioritize adding table support. It would be so useful to so many people.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Slack has no built-in support to render tables in messages.

Your workaround options are:

- Draw table with chars in the message using a monospace font ([Example](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?mode=message&blocks=%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%60%60%60%2B------------%2B------------%2B-----------%2B%5Cn%7C%20Header%201%20%20%20%7C%20Header%202%20%20%20%7C%20Header%203%20%20%7C%5Cn%2B%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%2B%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%2B%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%2B%5Cn%7C%20body%20row%201%20%7C%20column%202%20%20%20%7C%20column%203%20%20%7C%5Cn%2B------------%2B------------%2B-----------%2B%60%60%60%22%7D%7D%5D))
- Draw table with chars and upload as plain text snippet with `files.upload`
- Render table as image and attach to a message or upload as image

Answer (score 11):

I used tabluate in python for create a formatted table from pandas dataframe then I posted the table using slack python client's chat_postMessage method using below technique:

````
client.chat_postMessage(channel="#dummy-channel",text="```\n" + table + "\n```")
````

Note ```` "```\n" + table + "```\n" ```` is being used to convert `table` into code block just like we as users do in slack.

Comment: This is really interesting. I'm going to have to check out that capability!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using the `tabulate` library, with the triple backticks trick! And it turned out that `tabulate` has a variety of table formats as well. :)

Comment: ohhh #lifesaver

Answer (score 4):

First convert to markdown

```
markdown_table = df.to_markdown()
```

Prepare data to send to the webhook url via `requests.post`

````
slack_data = {"text":"```\n" + markdown_table + "\n```"}
````

Comment: what object/type is `df`?

Comment: Inferring from context: pandas dataframe. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html

Answer (score 1):

Above are great efforts and user need good libraries for having table in the slack.

I have been using prettytable module of python to convert my tablular data into pretty table and post them as code block get my perfect tables in slack messages.

```py
pip install prettytable
```

```py
from prettytable import PrettyTable

# Create a PrettyTable instance
table = PrettyTable()

# Define columns
table.field_names = ["Name", "Age", "City"]

# Add data rows
table.add_row(["Alice", 25, "New York"])
table.add_row(["Bob", 30, "San Francisco"])
table.add_row(["Charlie", 22, "Los Angeles"])

# Print the table
print(table)
```

```py
+---------+-----+---------------+
|  Name   | Age |      City     |
+---------+-----+---------------+
|  Alice  |  25 |   New York    |
|   Bob   |  30 | San Francisco |
| Charlie |  22 | Los Angeles   |
+---------+-----+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2024:

[Canvas](https://slack.com/help/articles/203950418-Use-a-canvas-in-Slack) in Slack helps you to create simple tables. You can paste table from clipboard, make comments and mention people too.

[image: Choose Canvas on the top right corner]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This could be a nice solution, but need to verify that their API supports the creation and sharing of Canvases. In addition, it limits the Canvas preview, so that wouldn't work for large amount of rows.

Answer (score -2):

If your data is simple with up to one text column and some number columns, try this.

---

**Landing page report (views, buys)**

`1754`    `17` https://example.com/variant-a

`1834`    `23` https://example.com/variant-b

Comment: Woah, I love this solution. adding two `markdown` columns I was even able to add a header. So long as you fill the columns to the same width.

    *Success   Failure    Job*\n`  3456`   `  4567`  Do something\n

Comment: Upvoted, it is a good idea. I have no idea why this answer is currently at -2.