# What is the best way to render more than 3 or 4 columns data in slack response in table like structure?

Tags: markdown, slack, slack-block-kit

I have to render  tables in Slack with more than 4 columns of data, and that should not break even when Slack is not full screen or a small resolution on the phone

I explored various approaches on the web, googled, and even chat GPT but none of the solutions is up to the mark for this simple use case. I checked the option in [How to render tables in Slack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006831/how-to-render-tables-in-slack) but that breaks as the columns grow or the window gets smaller

Another option I tried was a markdown table, which also did not work

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Hello, Assistant to the Regional Manager Dwight! *Michael Scott* wants to know where you'd like to take the Paper Company investors to dinner tonight.\n\n *Please select a restaurant:*"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "| Restaurant | Cuisine | Price |\n|------------|---------|-------|\n| Le Bernardin | French | $$$$ |\n| Xi'an Famous Foods | Chinese | $ |\n| Shake Shack | American | $$ |\n| Blue Hill | American | $$$$ |\n| Katz's Delicatessen | Jewish | $$ |"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And HTML table also does not work, skipping snippet as it is obvious.